# Error with CTAS - Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: temp-tables, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a temp table in Synapse SQL using CTAS

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp 
AS SELECT [State], LocalizedLabel FROM StateMetadata WHERE EntityName ='incident'
```

and getting an error message

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
> Total execution time: 00:00:00.533

[Error message snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT1v4.png)

If I run SELECT statement by itself as highlighted it works

```
SELECT [State], LocalizedLabel FROM StateMetadata WHERE EntityName ='incident'
```

[Select statement that works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKg6A.png)

and if I create temp table without using AS, it works fine as well

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    statecode int,
    statecodename nvarchar(64)
    )
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

[Create temp table without using AS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwL9C.png)

I have tried brackets and everything I could. Not sure what I am possibly doing wrong. I am new to Synapse Analytics, Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Nidhi

Answer (score 1):

`CTAS` requires a distribution option while creating. Include distribution options while creating temp tables using [CTAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7#i-use-ctas-instead-of-selectinto).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
WITH
(
  DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
)
AS
SELECT StateName, StateCode FROM SP WHERE Region ='US';

select * from #temp
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Niharika, thanks for the reply. It still doesn;t work for me. I am getting error:  Incorrect syntax near 'DISTRIBUTION'.

Comment: Any other suggestions you may have?